# Remove Debug build configuration as default on an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-3.1

On an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application CSProj file I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'development'">
  <ConfigurationGroup>Debug</ConfigurationGroup>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So I set a 'development' build configuration which is basically the debug configuration.

When I simply use `dotnet build` the project is built with Debug configuration.

To use the development configuration I need to use `dotnet build -c development`.

Is it possible to set `development` configuration as default so it is used by:

dotnet build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most csproj files you see assignment of variables to a default value like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I think in your case you want something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">development</Configuration>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That didn't work ... It seems the dotnet tool sends Debug for default so I need to use:  `<Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">development</Configuration>`